# Javascript scoping - parents siblings

Tags: javascript, scope

In the example below I'm trying to access the parents sibling.  Is there a better way than what I've come up with, what gives?

Broken:

```
var funkyness = function(){

    var some_obj = {
        foo: function() {
            alert('bar');
        },

        'wrapper' : {
            'OK': function() { 
                // I want to access some_obj.foo
                foo(); // foo is not defined
            }
        }
    }

    some_obj.wrapper.OK();
};
```

Seems like a hack fix:

```
var funkyness = function(){
    var afoo;
    var some_obj = {
        foo: function() {
            alert('bar');
        },

        'wrapper' : {
            'OK': function() { 
                // I want to access some_obj.foo
                afoo();
            }
        }
    }

    afoo = some_obj.foo;
    some_obj.wrapper.OK();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use:

```
var funkyness = function(){

 var some_obj = {
  foo: function() {
   alert('bar');
  },

  'wrapper' : {
   'OK': function() {
     debugger;
    // I want to access some_obj.foo
    some_obj.foo(); // foo is a member of some_obj
   }
  }
 }

 some_obj.wrapper.OK();
};
```

Comment: Wow.  I feel like an idiot - that had to be one of the first things I tried.  I must have typo'ed it or something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a prototype?

```
some_obj.prototype.foo = function() 
{
    // bleh
}
```